# Is there any difference between 'At this point' and 'To this point'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, difference, american-english

Example:

"At/to this point, I just want to be happy."

Are they interchangeable? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the context?

Comment: Please do not use wanna here. wanna is an informal way to say want to but it's best not used in writing unless you are writing a dialogue or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not interchangeable. In your example, without context, the "to" form is probably not correct.

"At this point" is referring to the specific time. It means "right now." You can substitute "right now" for it.

- At this point, I have twelve pairs of socks.
- Right now, I have twelve pairs of socks.

"To this point" can mean at least two things. Because you are using it with "at this point" you probably mean "up to the current time."

- To this point, I have purchased twelve pairs of socks.
- From the start until now, I have purchased twelve pairs of socks.

You can see they are related but not interchangeable. If you have purchased twelve pairs of socks you probably have twelve pairs of socks. But the two phrases are referring to the present instant in time (at this point) or the portion of time leading up to now (to this point).

Context will be required to determine how much of the past to include in "to this point." For example, it might be from the start of a particular shopping trip.

For completeness, "to this point" has other possible meanings. For example, if somebody is having a discussion with you, you might want to talk about a particular thing they have said.

Fred: You don't have enough socks.
Bill: To this point, how many socks is enough?

You could also use "to your point."

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not:

- *At this point in the conversation*, I would like to tell that [blah blah blah].
- *At this point in our lives*, etc.
- *In response *to that point you made* about purple roses*, I'd like to say [blah blah blah.] For example.

*at* is used to indicate a point in time or a place.

to this point is not a phrase by itself.

Comment: Hmm... To this point, everything was fine. At this point everything went wrong.

Comment: Hmm... I don't find *To this point, everything was fine* idiomatically acceptable. But ***Up to...*** (or ***Up until...***) are both fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said that just *to this point* is not right. It would be: In response **to this point**. There is no need for up to. That is different from what I'm sayng.

Comment: Sorry, I was addressing @BobaFit's comment. I thought cut&pasting ***Hmm...*** would convey that, but I was mistaken.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, I didn't even see that. I think it wasn't up when I read your comment.